# Accessing private member variables within a class: Why does this work?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code snippet:

```
class cor {
    int x;

  public:
    cor();
    cor(int a) {
        x = a;
    }
    int operator +(cor other) {
        return x + other.x; // Allowed. 'other' accessing a private member
    }
    void getx() {
        cout << x; 
    }
};

int main() {
    cor a(5);
    cor b(10);
    cor c = a+b;
    cout << c.x; // ERROR. 'x' is a private member.
}
```

Why is the 'private' member access treated differently inside the main and inside the class definition? Isnt 'c' declared in main() the same as 'other' that is accepted as the argument? Why are these behaving differently?

Comment: Isn't that the whole point of a private variable? You should read more about classes and encapsulation

Comment: That's really basic material covered in every C++ book or even online tutorial. You cannot expect to understand a programming language without reading a lot of teaching material.

Comment: Yes. But 'c' declared in main is just another object like 'other' But 'other' is able to access a private variable whereas 'c' is not. This confuses me. @awesomeyi

Comment: Did you ever think why there are 3 access specifiers (private, protected, public) in C++? Explore on this you will get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other works because you define operator+ for type cor, in all methods of class cor ( public or private ) you are allowed to call private and public members. In this operator other variable is of the same type, so according to this rule you are allowed to call other.x. In main function you are out of this scope so it is reason why this will not work.

Another thing ( just for information ) is that you perform operation of + on two objects and as a result int is returned then implicit constructor is called

```
using namespace std;

class cor {

    int x;
public:
    cor();
    cor(int a)
    {
        cout << "Constructor " << a << endl;
        x = a;
    }
    int operator +(cor other)
    {
        return x+other.x; // Allowed. 'other' accessing a private member

    }
    void getx()
    {
        cout<<x;

    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cor a(5);
    cor b(10);
    cor c = a+b;
    //     cout<<c.x; // ERROR. 'x' is a private member.
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Constructor 5
Constructor 10
Constructor 15
```

If modify a little this source

```
using namespace std;

class cor {

    int x;
public:
    cor();
    explicit cor(int a)
    {
        cout << "Constructor " << a << endl;
        x = a;
    }
    int operator +(cor other)
    {
        return x+other.x; // Allowed. 'other' accessing a private member

    }
    void getx()
    {
        cout<<x;

    }

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cor a(5);
    cor b(10);
    cor c = a+b;
    //     cout<<c.x; // ERROR. 'x' is a private member.
    return 0;
}
```

You will get

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:37:14: error: conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'cor' requested
     cor c = a+b;
              ^
main.cpp: At global scope:
main.cpp:33:5: warning: unused parameter 'argc' [-Wunused-parameter]
 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
     ^
```

Answer (score 3):

Access modifiers are class-specific, not object-specific<sup>1</sup>:

See the standard (emphasis mine):

> **11 Member access control**
>
> A member of a class can be
>
> — `private`; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends **of the class** in which it is declared.
>
> ....

Within `cor`

```
return x+other.x
```

is valid, because `other` has type `cor` too.

---

1. With some special rules though, as **@ChristianHackl** commented.

Comment: Note, however, that this is not strictly true for `protected` access.

Comment: The standard defines several special rules for `protected` access (see 11.4 "Protected member access"). For example, the following will not work because access is not through `this`: `class Base { protected: int x; }; class Derived : public Base { void f(Base& b) { b.x = 0; }};`.